# How do I get reverse() to work in a function based view

Tags: django, view, django-templates

I am new to Django, and I would like to try a FBV for an activity that doesn't require a Model. This will eventually implement a search with user-defined parameters and show the results in the template, but for now my template and views are essentially empty to show this problem.

I'm using python 3.6 and Django 2.1.3.

The tutorials go straight to CBV and I'm having a hard time getting good info on the FBV way.

```
File: 'positivepets/picture_search.html':
-------
{% extends 'positivepets/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
    <p> You have reached the picture search page </p>
{% endblock %}


File: urls.py
--------
app_name = 'positivepets'

urlpatterns = [...
    url(r'^picture_search/$', views.misc_views.picture_search, name='picture_search'),
...]


File: misc_views.py
--------
def picture_search(request):
    return render(request, 'positivepets/picture_search.html')
```

### Problem

This all works fine and renders the template `picture_search.html`.

My problem is that I want to avoid hardcoding the template name.  I thought this would work:

```
def picture_search(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('positivepets:picture_search'))
```

This takes the user to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/positivepets/picture_search/`
but produces a "too many redirects" error in chrome.  I think I am just telling it to redirect to itself over and over.

### Question

Where do I specify that `picture_search.html` is the template that I want to render without hardcoding it in the view?

It seems that the answer should lie in `reverse`, but I can only find CBV examples of `reverse()`, and I think it works with CBV because there is a template_name attribute set in the class definition.  FBV doesn't have that, of course.

I'm hoping this is an easy one for someone with some FBV experience.

Comment: Well here you redirect to the function itself, so the redirect, will trigger the same view *again*, hence another redirect, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any benefit in doing what you're trying to do. You have to tell django what template you want by name somewhere. If you don't do it in your return, but somewhere else in your code you've only added a layer of abstraction with no net benefit.

i.e

```
def picture_search(request):
    return render(request, reverse('some_pointer'))
```

`some_pointer = 'picture_search'` - you still have to hard code it

= No benefit

the reverse function is for getting the url from the view, or the label.

At the end of that url is some function to render a template, with the template name.

Comment: Thanks - helpful to know it is acceptable to refer to the html filename in the view.